# How  ${\left(\frac 12 \right)}^{{\lg n}}$ = ${\frac 1n}$ for any natural number $n$?

Tags: arithmetic, logarithms

Consider binary logarithm . How is the value of ${(\frac 12 )}^{{\lg n}}$  = ${\frac 1n}$?

I was going [through this video of skiplists](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-12-skip-lists/) and the professor at 53:22 seconds make this claim .

Comment: @BabakSorouh lg is log to the base 2.(binary logarithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lg n} = \frac{1^{\lg n}}{2^{\lg n}} = \frac{1}{2^{\lg n}} = \frac{1}{n}
$$

Note that $2^{\lg n} = n$ because $2^{\lg n} = \left(e^{\log 2}\right)^{\lg n} = \left(e^{\log 2}\right)^{\log(n)/\log(2)} = e^{\log n} = n$.

Also, a lot of people write $\log_2 n$ instead of $\lg n$.

Comment: Or $2^{\lg n}=n$ because $\lg n$ is defined to be the $x$ such that $2^x=n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that is really more intuitive than this formal prrof. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall\,0<x,a\in\Bbb R\,\,,\,\,a^x=e^{x\log a}\Longrightarrow \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\log n}=e^{\log n\log 1/2}=\left(e^{\log n}\right)^{\log 1/2}=n^{\log1/2}$$

I think your equality is missing the $\,\log 1/2\,$ as power...

**Added:** But we can write
$$n^{\log 1/2}=n^{-\log 2}=\frac{1}{n^{\log 2}}$$

Comment: Please see my edited question .

Comment: Watch out: $\lg(n)=\ln(n)/\ln(2)$.

Comment: This must be a new symbol: never saw it before.